# UITableView freezes when scrolled too fast to top/bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which could be dragged from bottom using a swipe gesture and after swiping up more than a certain distance it takes up the entire screen. But I am unable to scroll up the contents. If I scroll up/down fast a few times it starts scrolling, but still it misses a few swipes while it is scrolling.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

(I am using iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1 for testing)

**EDIT:**
I just figured out that a specific lower part of my tableview is not receiving any touch inputs.

Comment: Are you doing any extra work on tableview's cellforrowIndexpath method like web service something ?

Comment: No, I am not. And I just figured out that a specific lower part of my tableview is not receiving any touch events.

Comment: maybe yours view under TableVview have wrong frame?

Comment: @Yuri The frame of my tableview's container view was wrong. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.